# Illustrator join anchor points separate paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point, borders

I have three objects/paths with a fill and a border.

[image]

Why are the end points of the border not consistent with the angles despite the path in outline mode showing the anchors are 'snapped' together?

How can I get a regular box with borders as shown? I've tried inside/center/outside but nothing seems to work. It seems so basic but so difficult at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: Use round linecaps and joins.

Comment: I need a sharp edge rather than rounded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the box to display "sharp" corners, you can try this:

1. Duplicate your objects, so that you can return to them should you need to edit their dimensions later.
2. Select the three objects and Object > Expand (fill and stroke). (Expands the appearance of your fill and stroke, so that you can edit out the parts you don't want. However, after your stroke is expanded it is difficult to resize.)
3. Apply Pathfinder "Divide." (Breaks apart the parts that you want to delete.)
4. Delete the tiny miter "triangles" that are extending beyond the corners.

The resulting box will look like what you want; however, if you then need to edit the box dimensions, you'll want to make those edits on your duplicate box and redo steps 2-4. (Yeah, it's a pain.)

Comment: Doesn't this seem strange that even in CC 2016 we still can't make two adjacent path anchor points meet at the same sharp end point?

Comment: @MrBullets not really. That would mean a much more complex object model. Given that the nodel is allready too compllicated to most people that wouldnt make things easier. Idea is to design the edges you want to control.