# How to control strokes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

My stroke is bleeding, and I was wondering how to clean up dirty stroke corners.

I'm creating a simple envelope for a newsletter (rectangle and triangle), but the triangle stroke is bleeding over. Aligning the stroke to the inside or outside doesn't allow me to match the corners how I want.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

[image]

The image on the left is a triangle over a rectangle, and the right is a rectangle and two lines that don't match.

Comment: One way to approach this is to expand the triangle and rectangle and then use Pathfinder divide to help delete the miter points that are sticking out at the top. I explained this process in a [recent answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74838/67895).

Answer (score 3):

Try to set a lower value for the Corner Limit. This cuts long tails in the case of acute corners. Experiment with it because the threshold value depends on the angle.

[image]